# How to return double[] in jni input argument

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface, arguments

In my Java code I have defined the following function signature:

```
public native boolean getData( double [] data );
```

In my C++ code I'd like to populate the double array data to return back to Java, and the returned boolean from the function will indicate whether the data was set correctly or not.

javah created the following C++ function signature:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_test_getData___3D( JNIEnv* pEnv, jclass cls, jdoubleArray dArray )
```

How do I implement this function in C++ so that I can return 3 double values generated in the C++ code?

I'd like to do something similar to this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077554/learn-java/java-tip-54--returning-data-in-reference-arguments-via-jni.html  Just instead of using a StringBuffer, I'd like to fill in the array of doubles with values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_test_getData___3D( JNIEnv* pEnv, jclass cls, jdoubleArray dArray )
{
    jboolean isCopy1;
    jdouble* srcArrayElems = 
           pEnv->GetDoubleArrayElements(dArray, &isCopy1);
    jint n = pEnv->GetArrayLength(dArray);
    jboolean res = false;

    // here update srcArrayElems values, maybe set res to true

    if (isCopy1 == JNI_TRUE) {
       pEnv->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(dArray, srcArrayElems, JNI_ABORT);
    }
    return res ;
}
```

When calling getdata your array must be already allocated - it means be of correct length.

I have not compiled this code, you can find lots of samples on google, here are some good links:

http://www.ict.nsc.ru/win/docs/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/array.html
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~naras/java/course/lec5/lec5.html

Comment: perfect!  Thanks I didn't realize that the values would get written back to the array when Release was called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a Boolean, consider returning a tuple of doubles: {x, y, z, isValid} where isValid == 0 means "false".

```
jdoubleArray Java_com_test_getData__3D(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
  double xyzValid[4];
  populateMyData(xyzValid);

  jdoubleArray jXyzValid = env->NewDoubleArray(4);
  env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(jXyzValid , 0, 4, xyzValid);

  return jXyzValid;
}
```

Another option might be to return {x, y, z} for success, and NULL for failure.